# How to use bluetooth already connected by iPhone in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios-bluetooth

I need to use bluetooth for my app. I only want to use the bluetooth connected by my iPhone. I found code blow for bluetooth:

```
///bluetooth scan for devices
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
    if central.state == .PoweredOn {
        central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    } else {
        print("Bluetooth not available.")
    }
}

///bluetooth connect to a device
func centralManager(
    central: CBCentralManager,
    didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                          advertisementData: [String : AnyObject],
                          RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print("--didDiscoverPeripheral-")

    print(peripheral.name)

    //central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    /*let device = (advertisementData as NSDictionary)
        .objectForKey(CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey)
        as? NSString

    if device?.containsString(self.BEAN_NAME!) == true {
        self.manager.stopScan()

        self.peripheral = peripheral
        self.peripheral.delegate = self

        manager.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
    }*/
}

///bluetooth get services
func centralManager(
    central: CBCentralManager,
    didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
}

///bluetooth get characteristics
func peripheral(
    peripheral: CBPeripheral,
    didDiscoverServices error: NSError?) {
    for service in peripheral.services! {
        let thisService = service as CBService

        if service.UUID == BEAN_SERVICE_UUID {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(
                nil,
                forService: thisService
            )
        }
    }
}

///bluetooth setup notifications
func peripheral(
    peripheral: CBPeripheral,
    didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService,
                                         error: NSError?) {
    for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
        let thisCharacteristic = characteristic as CBCharacteristic

        if thisCharacteristic.UUID == BEAN_SCRATCH_UUID {
            self.peripheral.setNotifyValue(
                true, 
                forCharacteristic: thisCharacteristic
            )
        }
    }
}

///bluetooth changes are coming
func peripheral(
    peripheral: CBPeripheral,
    didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic,
                                    error: NSError?) {
    var count:UInt32 = 0;

    if characteristic.UUID == BEAN_SCRATCH_UUID {
        characteristic.value!.getBytes(&count, length: sizeof(UInt32))

    }
}

///bluetooth disconnect and try again
func centralManager(
    central: CBCentralManager,
    didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                            error: NSError?) {
    central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
}
```

This code scan bluetooth, but I think I don't need to scan bluetooth. How to use the bluetooth which is **already connected** by iPhone ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Quick questions: Are you really using Bluetooth Low-Energy devices? If not, you can't use `CoreBluetooth.framework` for that. If your device is not BLE, is it MFi? What kind of device exactly?

Comment: I do not know much more about bluetooth. I chose "Uses bluetooth LE accessories" and "Acts as a Bluetooth LE accessory" for background modes, and it works, but I need reconnect bluetooth of iPhone. Now, I want to use bluetooth which is already connected by my iPhone, not only in background mode and reconnection. Can you help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the peripheral is already connected to the phone, your app needs to make a connection. You either need to discover the peripheral, or if you have previously discovered it, get a new instance using `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers`. Once you have the peripheral instance you can connect to it.

Comment: Thank you Paulw11 for your answer. how to discover peripheral? Use les codes I posted? is there an function to get Identifier the bluetooth which is already connected by iPhone or not? because I can scan many peripherals, and I just want to use the bluetooth which is already connected by iPhone.